# Magento - Coupon Question

Tags: magento

My coupons need to do the following:

The coupon area is based on a minimum of 10 people odering the same item before the coupon comes in to effect.

When a user signs up, An email will be sent to each person saying that his credit card won't be charged until the deal comes in to effect (10 people ordered this item).

So until the 10th person orders the same item, no one’s credit card will be charged.

As soon as the 10th person signs-up, all 10 people will have their credit cards charged and an email confirmation 
sent to them.

Is there an article on this? 
Does a plugin already exist for this?

If not, what file(s) should I be looking at?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Magento are you using? There are a lot of files that possibly could be affected by this.

Comment: you need to demonstrate that you have made an attempt at programming this. Paste in some code, or tell us the results of your investigation.  Stack Overflow is intended to answer specific programming issues, not providing architectural design services

Answer (score 0):

This would be an interesting project.  To do it properly, you aren't going to be able to save the credit card information.  So, you'll need to tap into the resources offered by whatever payment gateway you will be using.  Hopefully they'll let you hold either the users payment information for a while, or an extended authorization.  There will certainly be a good amount of programming involved to monitor how many were sold for a particular "deal", and when the number is satisfied, take care of fully processing all of the orders.

This isn't really a coupon question though, in terms of the coupon codes in Magento.  What you want to do, Magento cannot do without writing a module/extension to do this.  It will not be a straight-forward, simple task.